# Pioneer f60dab video bypass (not parking brake)

Tags: electrical

Can anyone help, I've bought a transport t5. 1, which is fitted with a pioneer f60dab for some reason their is no green parking brake wire, it will let me watch video up to 5mph, the I get the warning, I can't find out how to bypass this as everything on YouTube is parking brake related and the green wire, mine is speed related, any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score -1):

DISCLAIMER: I don't recommend this and you do it at your own risk.

That said, there should be a pink wire which connects to a speed sensor. The [installation manual](https://catalogs.pioneer-car.eu/Manuals/AVIC_F60DAB__installation_manual/?page=10) states, this should be connected to help with the nav features. I'm pretty sure this also gives the head unit the speed the vehicle is moving for your video output. I don't know this for sure, though.